# move Drupal 7 from remote server to localhost

Tags: php, drupal-7

i create backup `drupal(7.12)` files and `mysql` database from remote server(online site) for run my site in `localhost(xampp)`.

`NOTE: my website is in root: www.domain.com and localhost is : localhost/test2`

i change `settnigs.php` in `sites/default/settings.php` for mysql database config and import backup `mysql` to new `mysql` database(localhost). now my localhost load very slow my website without theme and when i login with `administrator` my admin `user/pass` not valid and not work. how to fix this?

OR, what's better/worked way for moved drupal 7 from remote server(online site) to localhost!?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to find localhost slower than the online site due too server capapilities.
If you mean with "load very slow my website without theme" that you have a white screen with text only, then you may need to increase php memory_limit and max_execution_time in your php.ini file or there are missing files on localhost so you need to backup your files again from online site and make sure you have read permission to all files.